# GCP Bigquery Error in Load Operation: Bytes are Missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gzip, bq

I am very new to Google Cloud Platform and I'm trying to create a table in bigquery from ~60,000 `csv.gz` files stored in a GCP bucket.

To do this, I've opened Cloud Shell, and I'm trying the following:

```sh
$ bq --location=US mk my_data
$ bq --location=US \
     load --null_marker='' \
     --source_format=CSV --autodetect \
     my_data.my_table gs://my_bucket/*.csv.gz
```

This throws the following error:

```sh
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my_job:bqjob_r3eede45779dc9a51_0000017529110a63_1': 
Error while reading data, error message:
FAILED_PRECONDITION: Invalid gzip file: bytes are missing
```

I don't know how to find which file might be problematic when loading the files. I've checked a few of the files, and they are all valid `.gz` files that I can open with any csv reader after decompression, but I don't know how to check through all the files to find a problematic one.

Thank you in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through your bucket, you can use the eval command

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="gsutil ls gs://YOUR_BUCKET"
RESULTS=$(eval $FILES)
for f in $RESULTS
do
  read="gsutil cat $f | zcat | wc -c"
  if [[ $(eval $read) == "0" ]]
    then
        #<Process it, Print name or Delete from bucket like below>
        delete="gsutil rm $f"
        eval $delete
    fi
done
```

Another option is to [download all your files locally](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp), if possible, and process from there:

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://YOUR_BUCKET .
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be .gz files that do not contain any data within. You might want to write a script which will filter if the .gz files are valid.

This sample bash script will do a directory loop through the .gz files and delete them if they are empty.

```
for f in dir/*
do
    if [[ $(gunzip -c $f | head -c1 | wc -c) == "0" ]] 
    then
        do_file_creation
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Rally H! Do you know how I can run this as a bash commend for a directory in a GCP bucket?